# Unclear why bootstrap-react-table2 is not creating pagination

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap-table

I have setup a bootstrap-react-table2. It is displaying styles appropriately (such as condensed, striped, etc), but the pagination is not displaying. I have checked and re-rechecked the installation instructions, but I don't think I have missed any steps.

Here is my module which loads the data, table, and attempts to set up the pagination...

```
import React from 'react';
import BootstrapTable from 'react-bootstrap-table-next/lib/src/bootstrap-table';
import paginationFactory from 'react-bootstrap-table2-paginator';
import 'react-bootstrap-table2-paginator/dist/react-bootstrap-table2-paginator.min.css';
// Temporary Data
import ContactContent from '../components/contacts-list';

const ContactsPage = () => {

  const columns = [{
      dataField: 'firstName',
      text: 'First Name'
    }, {
      dataField: 'lastName',
      text: 'Last Name'
    }, {
        dataField: 'org',
        text: 'Organization'
    }, {
      dataField: 'phone',
      text: 'Phone Number'
  }];


  return (
    <>
      <h1>Contacts</h1>
      <BootstrapTable 
bootstrap4 keyField='id' data={ ContactContent } columns={ columns } striped hover condensed pagination={ paginationFactory() }  />        
    </>
  );
}

export default ContactsPage;
```

Comment: Just try this `import BootstrapTable from 'react-bootstrap-table-next';`

Comment: I tired that and it instead crashed the web app. It gives this error: ```TypeError: props.pagination.createContext is not a function```